# Simple or compound sentence

Tags: grammar

What makes the following a simple sentence?

> James cleaned and polished his brother's car.

Isn't this a compound sentence made of two simple sentences

"James cleaned his brother's car." and "James polished his brother's car."?

Answer (score 1):

> "James cleaned and polished his brother's car".

It's a simple sentence because it only contains one independent clause, i.e. the sentence as a whole.

It does, however, contain a coordination of two verb phrases, so the structure is:

> "James [cleaned __ ] [and polished __ ] his brother's car".

Both coordinates contain a 'gap' __' (representing the objects of the verbs) co-indexed with the NP "his brother's car" in postnuclear position.

Answer (score 0):

> "James cleaned and polished his brother's car."

The above is a simple sentence because it contains only a main clause -- no subordinate clause, no coordinate clause.  Using a compound subject doesn't make a sentence a compound sentence.  To be a compound sentence, the sentence must contain a coordinate clause, another part of the sentence introduced by a coordinating conjunction that has its own subject-verb.

> "James cleaned his brother's car, and James polished his brother's
>   car."

The above is a compound sentence because it contains a main clause ("James cleaned his brother's car") and a coordinate clause ("and James polished his brother's car").  Your sentence may mean the same thing as that, but it doesn't actually say that, and the fact that it doesn't actually say that is the reason it's not a compound sentence.

Comment: I think  in a compound sentences both  are  coordinate  independent clauses.There is no main clause.

Comment: @Nancy – you may want to change the bit about compound subject, since it implies that the sentence given in the OP has a coordinated subject (which it doesn't). Just a thought :)

Comment: @Hannah is right, Nancy. It doesn't have a compound subject, but a compound verb phrase. See my answer below.